# Calculate Hamming distance between integers with bitwise operations

Tags: c#, bitwise

I recently learned about the Hamming distance. The use-case I found it through was actually working with integers instead of strings, yet its implementation was using string comparison. I was pretty sure it could be done with bitwise operations, and from what I can tell, my implementation is successful.

```
public int HammingDistance(int x, int y) {
    int xor = x ^ y;
    int distance = 0;
    while (xor > 0) {
        distance++;
        xor &= xor - 1;
    }

    return distance;
}
```

However, I can't help but wonder if this makes the code harder to understand for others. Additionally, is there a way to eliminate the `while` loop but still count the number of set bits in the `xor` result in a more efficient manner?

<sub>*Feel free to test it out on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RxvAID).*</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was pretty sure it could be done with bitwise operations

You are right.

> my implementation is successful

No. Think of negative `x` (or negative `y`). The loop would terminate immediately.

> if this makes the code harder to understand for others

No. Anybody who understands Hamming distance shall understand this bit-fiddling.

> is there a way to eliminate the while loop

I don't know a portable way. For the native integral datatypes, all major architectures have a `popcount` instruction. `gcc` offers it as a `__builtin_popcount`. [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) offers `std::popcount`. In all mainstream architectures both map to a single instruction. I am sure that [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) does not lag.

For the integral larger than native (like `BigInteger` and the family), the answer is no.

Comment: BTW the built-in popcount function in C# is found in `System.Numerics.BitOperations.PopCount` (Core 3.0 and later)